# R data frame subsetting returns an unexpected column

Tags: r, subset

I have this situation that I don't get.

I have a data frame SampleA with 28 columns:

```
    > str(sampleA)
'data.frame':   400000 obs. of  28 variables:
 $ residence               : Factor w/ 2 levels "Domestic","International": 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ part_number             : int  8002 8002 8002 8002 8002 8002 8002 8002 8002 8002 ...
 $ is_intraoral            : int  1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ doc_level               : int  1 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ doc_country             : Factor w/ 100 levels "AD ","AE ","AM ",..: 16 32 96 96 96 96 96 19 33 16 ...
 $ upper_posterior_att_v   : int  2 1 3 4 2 3 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ upper_anterior_att_v    : int  3 2 2 4 1 4 3 1 2 3 ...
 $ lower_posterior_att_v   : int  1 2 1 3 2 2 2 4 2 2 ...
 $ lower_anterior_att_v    : int  1 4 1 4 4 1 1 1 4 1 ...
 $ plan_cBL_v              : int  3 4 2 4 1 4 2 3 3 1 ...
 $ plan_cMD_v              : int  2 4 3 4 2 4 1 2 3 1 ...
 $ plan_cIE_v              : int  3 3 4 4 3 4 2 4 1 1 ...
 $ plan_rBL_v              : int  2 4 3 4 2 4 2 3 4 1 ...
 $ plan_rMD_v              : int  2 4 4 4 2 4 3 4 1 1 ...
 $ plan_rIE_v              : int  3 3 4 4 3 4 2 4 1 1 ...
 $ plan_inclination_v      : int  3 3 4 3 3 4 2 2 3 1 ...
 $ plan_rotation_v         : int  2 1 4 2 3 4 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ plan_angulation_v       : int  2 2 3 3 3 4 3 4 1 1 ...
 $ upper_post_total_space_v: int  4 1 1 4 1 1 4 4 1 1 ...
 $ upper_ant_total_space_v : int  4 1 1 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ lower_post_total_space_v: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 1 1 ...
 $ lower_ant_total_space_v : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 4 4 1 1 ...
 $ active_stages_v         : int  2 4 4 4 4 4 2 3 4 1 ...
 $ average_overbite_v      : int  1 3 1 1 3 2 3 4 3 3 ...
 $ average_overjet_v       : int  1 3 2 1 4 1 4 3 1 4 ...
 $ sum_ipr_v               : int  1 4 3 1 4 1 1 3 4 3 ...
 $ patient_age_v           : Factor w/ 2 levels "Adult","Teen": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ is_CC_v                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 ...
```

And I also have an integer vector of length 27:

```
round(sao$par)
 [1] 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

I try to subset SampleA by:

```
final_sample <- sampleA[, round(sao$par) == 1]
```

I am expecting to get a 17 variable dataframe, but for some reason I get an extra one, 18th:

```
> str(final_sample)
'data.frame':   400000 obs. of  18 variables:
 $ residence               : Factor w/ 2 levels "Domestic","International": 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ is_intraoral            : int  1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ doc_level               : int  1 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ lower_posterior_att_v   : int  1 2 1 3 2 2 2 4 2 2 ...
 $ plan_cBL_v              : int  3 4 2 4 1 4 2 3 3 1 ...
 $ plan_cMD_v              : int  2 4 3 4 2 4 1 2 3 1 ...
 $ plan_cIE_v              : int  3 3 4 4 3 4 2 4 1 1 ...
 $ plan_rBL_v              : int  2 4 3 4 2 4 2 3 4 1 ...
 $ plan_rMD_v              : int  2 4 4 4 2 4 3 4 1 1 ...
 $ plan_rIE_v              : int  3 3 4 4 3 4 2 4 1 1 ...
 $ plan_inclination_v      : int  3 3 4 3 3 4 2 2 3 1 ...
 $ plan_rotation_v         : int  2 1 4 2 3 4 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ plan_angulation_v       : int  2 2 3 3 3 4 3 4 1 1 ...
 $ upper_ant_total_space_v : int  4 1 1 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ lower_post_total_space_v: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 1 1 ...
 $ lower_ant_total_space_v : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 4 4 1 1 ...
 $ active_stages_v         : int  2 4 4 4 4 4 2 3 4 1 ...
 $ is_CC_v                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 ...
```

How can it be? Is my code doing something different?

Comment: it's probably that sao$par has 27 elements and your data.frame has 28 columns. You could do `sampleA[, c(round(sao$par)==1,FALSE)]`

Answer (score 0):

Your integer vector has length 27 while the data frame SampleA has 28 column. So, when you subset using the vector, you don't specify what to do for the 28th column in SampleA, i.e. to include it or to exclude it. In such cases, R repeats the vector you provide until it has a vector of length 28 to work with. For example, try subsetting with `c(1,0,0,0)`. You will find that every fourth variable in SampleA is included in the result. So, to get the result you are looking for, you should find the subset using `c(round(sao$par), 0) ==1`.